# Include * in arguments to a function for python

Tags: python

I have a requirement to include * in arguments to a function.
But it's syntactically wrong like below

```
>>> xr.bngConfig(get_topo*titan_file=self.inputs['titan_file'])
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I cannot change the argument here since bngConfig is calling a tcl function which has `-get_topo*titan_file` as argument which I can't change.

How can * be included in python call?

Answer (score 2):

[The hard way.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
xr.bngConfig(**{'get_topo*titan_file': self.inputs['titan_file']})
```